# What should be the `IEnumerable<T>` type for the content of a `.csv` file?

Tags: c#, linq

I have a `.csv` file (`Book1.csv`) including transitions of a finite state machine:

```
q_src,eve,q_dst
q0,sig1,q1
q1,sig2,q2
```

I need to write a method to find the result of a transition.

```
State FindDestination(State q0, Event s0)
{
    var transitions = File.ReadAllLines(@"Book1.csv").Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(','));
    State newq = from t in transitions
                 where t.q_src ==q0 && t.eve == s0
                 select new t.q_dst;
    return newq;
}
```

But it's not efficient because the method will read the file every time for each transition:

Now if I try to read the file once and pass its content to the method, I don't k
now what type should I use for the `transitions` in the method's argument:

```
var transitions = File.ReadAllLines(@"Book1.csv").Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(','));

State FindDestination(State q0, Event s0, ? transitions)   //?type
{
    State newq = from t in transitions
                 where t.q_src ==q0 && t.eve == s0
                 select new t.q_dst;
    return newq;
}
```

Furthermore, `State` and `Event` classes have only one attribute `Name`.

I've read that the rough ideas is using `IEnumerable<?>`, but what is the `?` type for a `.csv` file?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After splitting each line you will end up with `IEnumerable<string[]>`

```
IEnumerable<string[]> transitions = File.ReadAllLines(@"Book1.csv").Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(','));
```

Also all the types return would be `System.String`

```
string FindDestination(State q0, Event s0) {
    var transitions = File.ReadAllLines(@"Book1.csv").Skip(1).Select(x => x.Split(','));
    var newq = from t in transitions
                 where t[0] == q0.Name && t[1] == s0.Name
                 select t[2];

    return newq.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

So pass an `IEnumerable<string[]>` to the modified method

```
string FindDestination(State q0, Event s0, IEnumerable<string[]> transitions) {

    var newq = from t in transitions
                 where t[0] == q0.Name && t[1] == s0.Name
                 select t[2];

    return newq.FirstOrDefault();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As [ReadAllLines](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s2tte0y1(v=vs.110).aspx) returns a `string[]` `IEnumerable<string>` should be a valid match.